# how to alter "other" field label or change the label name

Tags: webforms

How to alter "other" field label or change the label name
Please see the image[image: Webform "other field"]

Also,

How to constrain the sum of these responses to be 100?
Please see the image

[image: Constrain the sum]

Answer (score 1):

For customizing the 'more items' see [Issue #2953803: Allow multiple value elements item(s) label to be customized](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2953803).

For 'How to constrain the sum of these responses to be 100?' you are going to have to write custom client-side and server-side validation code.